# How can I use an ActionListener to perform an action on mouse release/mouse up?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I have a JButton with an attached ActionListener. The action is performed when the button is clicked, but I want the action to be performed after the click (ie when the mouse button is released). How can I do this?

Comment: A **click** implies that the mouse button has been released. How does a “click” without releasing the button look like?

Comment: I think that click can be a little ambiguous. I meant that the mouse button was pressed but not released. Sorry my terminology wasn't 100% to your liking @Holger.

Comment: Your “terminology” is inconsistent. You said you want the action to be performed “when the mouse button is released” but now you’re saying you mean that that button “was pressed but not released”.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do this with an `ActionListener`. You will have to add a `MouseListener` and handle the `mouseReleased` event.

Example:

```
addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
  public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
  }

  public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO: add your code here
  }

  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
  }

  public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
  }

  public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
  }
});
```

Or even easier, with a `MouseAdapter`:

```
addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
  public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO: add your code here
  }
});
```

Comment: for me not, better are events from ButtonModel